# Hierarchies for relationships in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

as far as I know the smartest way to store hierarchies for node entities is to use the new label feature. Lets's suppose an entity is of type B where B is a subclass of A. Then the node is labeled by both A and B, right?

But what about hierarchies for relationships? Should several relationships be stored between two entities to model hierarchies for relationships? Should the type of the relationship differ or is it more meaningful to have the same type but different properties?

Currently I don't know what are the advantages for the different approaches, in particular, with respect to formulate queries afterwards.

Thank you for some ideas you have in mind,

Benny

Comment: I don't think there can be a general answer to that. Do you have an example domain? It'd be interesting to explore this type of question further in some forum (SO may not be the best place for open-ended discussions), but in general it seems to me usually to be a mistake to map concepts/objects to atomic graph structures (i.e. we should do actual object-graph mapping, not object-node mapping) and it is very easy to overuse labels.

Comment: Hi,
a possible example is that "isDaughterOf", "isSonOf" are subtypes of "isChildOf" when modeling a family tree. Or from biology when having a BiochemicalReaction you might want to model "isParticipantOf", "isEductOf", "isProductOf".

Comment: In this simple hierarchy I think it is sufficient when asking for all children to traverse both relationship types, but the hierarchy might become more complex and then, it is likely that you forget one relationship type in Cypher ((x)-[r:IS_DAUGHTER_OF,IS_SON_OF]->(y)). If you use only one type ((x)-[r:IS_CHILD_OF]->(y)) you have to add a property daughter / son.

So what is a good way to do it in Neo4j? Adding more relationships, or adding more properties?

Comment: Agree I'd like to see this discussed in a wider forum.  It's an interesting question, but there's no simple answer.  But FWIW, it seems like you *could* use labels to model class/subclass relationship.  Or a particular relationship type.  There's also the additional question about enforcing constraints on relationship types.  Needs a deeper discussion.   OP, consider posting to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/neo4j and post link here.

Comment: Hi, 
here is the link to the forum: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/neo4j/jBneO5cuHQQ